# What do i have to modify to move http to https on my wordpress website in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

I just upgraded my hosting to include SSL but it doesnt redirect all the website.

I modified in my wordpress admin area everything that it says on most tutorials.

Even included in my wp-config.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

The only problem that remains i think is my htaccess which contains:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/website/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/website/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/website\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

But i don't know what to modify without "killing" the website.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: _"but it doesnt redirect all the website"_ - meaning what? Give some proper examples of URLs that don't behave as they should, instead of just stating something so utterly vague.

Comment: sorry, i meant it doesnt redirects to https, the only page that is redirected to https is the homepage which i think is forced inside of wordpress Settings -> General

Comment: That's probably because you got the order wrong. Every request that does not match an existing file or folder gets rewritten to WP's index.php at the top, `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`- and the `L` flag says to end processing there. Put the HTTP to HTTPS redirect at the very top, before the default WP block.

Comment: I tried it, nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/website/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/website/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>

</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: initially it killed the website and then i modified

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

to

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

But it still gave some bugy errors and it wasnt showing the icons on the website

Comment: I have edit the code above. Can you please give a try with new one? If this doesn't work I will find you a solution in a hard way!

Comment: it still doesnt work, if i delete the www it only works for my homepage and the other pages get a 404 error

Comment: OK, let's start! Restore your htaccess file with the old one and install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-install-free-ssl/ Then check if everything its fine and look at your htaccess after.

Comment: I managed to fix the links with Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin, i was looking for alternative solutions in the meanwhile and this one worked. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you found the solution! Take care :)